# solidity-coverage error

Tags: truffle, coverage

I want to make code coverage for my project. I installed the solidity-coverage from this page: https://github.com/sc-forks/solidity-coverage

and then ran this command in truffle : `truffle run coverage`

and then truffle give me an error : `Error: solidity-coverage listed as a plugin, but not found in global or local node modules!`

why am I getting this error?

thank you.

Comment: Try running `solidity-coverage` from command-line.

Comment: I m getting this error again. also I checked the npm packages and the solidity-coverage shown as install: that's here`├── @openzeppelin/cli@2.7.2
├── @openzeppelin/contracts@2.5.0
├── bignumber.js@9.0.0
├── bn.js@5.1.1
├── solidity-coverage@0.7.2
└── truffle-assertions@0.9.2`

Comment: @sollover  I currently have the same problem. Have you now figured out how to find out the code coverage in truffle?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you installed `npm install --save-dev solidity-coverage` in local or `npm install -g solidity-coverage` in global
Because I see that your system have not install `solidity-coverage` succesfully